# Grouped Boxplots in R

Tags: r, boxplot, ggplot2

I want to draw the same exact graph in R. However, I want to consider two options:
(1) with one x axis for each of the genders &
(2) two different xaxes for each of the gender. Here is also the link for where I found the image: https://rpubs.com/WhataBurger/Anovatype3

Thanks for sharing the knowledge.

[image]

Comment: If you include some reproducible code (including some data so people can make examples, this would be a better fit at https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/603176/56940